# How to create dynamic submenus of submenu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, submenu

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Career</a>
        <ul>                
            <asp:Repeater ID="_rptSubMenu" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a href="#" ><%# Eval("career") %></a></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>         
</ul>
```

This is creating dynamic submenus . I want submenus under career like `asp.net` `php` etc from database. How to do?

Comment: I don;t have Idea to try

Comment: The I suggest you google for examples on how to create dynamic contents on a ASP.NET page using a database...